# Intersecting MultiLinestring based geodataframes with geopandas?

Tags: python, geopandas

I would like to perform the following operation using `geopandas`.

[image]

The segments are delimited by red points and the blue items are attribute information. My inputs are the first and second line segments and my output is the third line segment.

Initially I thought this would be an intersection operation, but I soon learned that `geopandas` can only intersect polygons, therefore something like:

`intersection = geopandas.overlay(split_lines, original_lines, how='intersection')`

returns the following error:

```
raise TypeError("overlay only takes GeoDataFrames with (multi)polygon "
TypeError: overlay only takes GeoDataFrames with (multi)polygon
```

This to me looks like a standard geoprocessing operation and I really hope I won't have to code this up from scratch. Are there any simplified ways to come up with the following result without having to code a custom function?

**EDIT**
Unfortunately I cannot get this to work for more complicated geometries such as

ORIGINAL_LINES

```
                                            geometry property
0  (LINESTRING (0 0, 6.656423206909781 4.43757029...        a
1  (LINESTRING (6.656423206909781 4.4375702913320...        b
2  (LINESTRING (8.070636769282876 5.8517838537051...        c
3  (LINESTRING (6.656423206909781 4.4375702913320...        d
4  (LINESTRING (10.98655022583197 1.9375702913320...        e
5  (LINESTRING (13.68293236472948 0.6224568509648...        a
6  (LINESTRING (17.54663566988575 -0.412819329445...        a
```

SPLIT_LINES

```
                                            geometry  susc
0  LINESTRING (0 0, 4.160264504318614 2.773481432...     1
1  LINESTRING (4.160264504318614 2.77348143208253...     2
2  LINESTRING (6.656423206909781 4.43757029133205...     3
3  LINESTRING (9.950815132334437 8.18950268263064...     4
4  LINESTRING (13.08444573742037 12.0857007308397...     5
5  LINESTRING (6.656423206909781 4.43757029133205...     4
6  LINESTRING (10.98655022583197 1.93757029133205...     3
7  LINESTRING (15.61478401730761 0.10481876075978...     2
```

The output seem to be a 1D line... which is incorrect for this application.

Comment: Have you tried sjoin() with op='intersection'? I can't remember if it works for multi-linestrings but I remember it would often work for me when overlay failed.

Comment: Are you working with actual 1-D lines like your illustration?

Comment: Yees I am working with actual 1D lines for this test. In reality however I wish to implement this for a 2D road network

Comment: I don't know if there's an easy gpd solution, but you could just make a Nx2 numpy array; first column is the x-coordinate, second column is the segment ID. Then just sort the array rows according to the first column. You'd need to do a little interfacing with shapely to get coordinates and re-build the final line, but that's pretty easy.

Comment: How about the attributes... and how does sorting by x value help? Could you please elaborate on this method a bit more?

Comment: Good point. I would make three columns, then. First one is x-coordinate, second one is line 1 segment id, third one is line 2 segment id. Then sort based on first row. Then loop through first column, and for each x-coordinate, check if the segment id has changed for both attributes. If not, store the last-used attribute, and if so, store the new attribute. The second two columns could have nan's wherever they don't change. Sorry if that's confusing. Maybe someone can still help with an easier solution.

Comment: How can you sort based on a row? Sorry but this is very unclear...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828059/sorting-arrays-in-numpy-by-column has some solutions; Steve's is the most compact but difficult to understand.

Comment: Theyre sorting based on columns there. You mention sorting based on a row,

Comment: That was a typo--you'd want to sort based on the first column (arrange all your x-coordinates from smallest to largest).

Comment: also you say "check if the segment ID has changed for both attributes" . But the columns are in fact `line_1_segment_ID` and `line_2_segment_ID`. Where are the attributes in this table you describe? x-coordinates do not correspond to records in this case.... two segments can share the same x coordinate

Comment: @Jon why did you delete your answer? All I needed was some indication on how it could be extended to 2D... I wasn't saying it was incorrect, just incomplete... Could you please put it back? I'll accept it if you provide some comment on how to extend to 2D

Comment: Since you're looking for something that works in 2D, I removed the answer so that others are more likely to help. Perhaps you could resubmit the question with the full requirements (and it would be very helpful if you'd include the shapefiles you want to do this with).

Comment: Its not possible to include shapefiles on SE. Besides I believe your script *can* be extended, I just don't know how. I guess I will accept it since I was not clear from the beginning on the requirements and I will try to work through it myself. If I can't figure it out I'll post another question

Comment: You can upload the shapefiles to a google drive or similar and post the link. That's pretty common here. If you can upload them, I feel confident there is a much better and cleaner solution that uses geopandas.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83800/discussion-on-question-by-user32882-intersecting-multilinestring-based-geodatafr).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: The following answer only works for the 1-D case. To extend it to 2-D, you will need to parameterize your links by the along-road distance, and replace the x-coordinate with the parameterized length. However, I'm fairly confident this is doable much simpler with Geopandas.

It would be too hard to give hints in the comments, so here's a script that should give you what you want. It's not written for efficiency--probably you could get geopandas to do what you want with some finegaling, but here ya go. It's also not written very generally, but that could be done if you have more than one attribute.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString
import numpy as np

slgeom = [[(0,0),(7,0)],[(7,0),(13,0)],[(13,0),(15,0)],[(15,0),(19,0)]]
geoms = []
for s in slgeom:
    geoms.append(LineString(s))
properti = ['a','b','c','d']
split_lines = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=geoms)
split_lines['property'] = properti

olgeom = [[(0,0),(5,0)],[(5,0),(7,0), (10,0)],[(10,0),(13,0),(15,0)],[(15,0),(19,0)]]
geoms = []
for o in olgeom:
    geoms.append(LineString(o))
susc = [1,2,3,4]
original_lines = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=geoms)
original_lines['susc'] = susc


# Do split lines
xs1 = []
attrib1 = []
for g, a in zip(split_lines.geometry.values, split_lines.property.values):
    x = g.coords.xy[0].tolist()
    xs1.extend(x)
    try:
        attrib1[-1] = a
    except:
        pass
    attrib1.extend([a for l in range(len(x))])

# Do originals
xs2 = []
attrib2 = []
for g, a in zip(original_lines.geometry.values, original_lines.susc.values):
    x = g.coords.xy[0].tolist()
    xs2.extend(x)
    try:
        attrib2[-1] = a
    except:
        pass
    attrib2.extend([a for l in range(len(x))])

# Create numpy array for sorting
allxs = list(set(xs1 + xs2))
x_forsort = []
a1_forsort = []
a2_forsort = []
for x in allxs:
    try:
        idx = xs1.index(x)
        a1_forsort.append(attrib1[idx])
    except:
        a1_forsort.append(None)
    try:
        idx = xs2.index(x)
        a2_forsort.append(attrib2[idx])
    except:
        a2_forsort.append(None)
forsort = np.transpose(np.array([allxs, a1_forsort, a2_forsort]))

# Now sort based on x value (1st column)
sorteds = forsort[forsort[:,0].argsort()]

# Work through the sorted lists to create segments with the appropriate attributes
# Store results in a dictionary
output = dict()
output['geometry'] = [] 
output['attrib_1'] = []
output['attrib_2'] = []
for i in range(len(sorteds)-1):

    # Store shapely linestring
    output['geometry'].append(LineString([(sorteds[i,0],0),(sorteds[i+1,0],0)]))

    # Store attributes
    if i == 0:
        output['attrib_1'].append(sorteds[i,1])
        output['attrib_2'].append(sorteds[i,2])
    else:
        if sorteds[i,1] is None:
            output['attrib_1'].append(output['attrib_1'][-1])
        else:
            output['attrib_1'].append(sorteds[i,1])

        if sorteds[i,2] is None:
            output['attrib_2'].append(output['attrib_2'][-1])
        else:
            output['attrib_2'].append(sorteds[i,2])

# Convert back to geopandas dataframe
out_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(output)
out_gdf.crs = original_lines.crs
```

Result:

```
out_gdf
Out[185]: 
  attrib_1  attrib_2                 geometry
0        a         1    LINESTRING (0 0, 5 0)
1        a         2    LINESTRING (5 0, 7 0)
2        b         2   LINESTRING (7 0, 10 0)
3        b         3  LINESTRING (10 0, 13 0)
4        c         3  LINESTRING (13 0, 15 0)
5        d         4  LINESTRING (15 0, 19 0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort, but using the example above I am getting an incorrect result. (Please see edit to original question)

Comment: @user32882 Try edited code. I get the expected output now. I had to add the "try" statements in the attrib loops.

Comment: Really nice. It does work I have to admit. Now I have to look through it to make sure I understand how it does the trick. Do you think this would also work for larger GeoDataFrames with LineStrings that are not necessarily contiguous? where intersections happen and what not?

Comment: Glad it works! Haha, I was afraid you'd want something more general. With a little modification it could work for gapped lines. I think there's also a much simpler way (might not be as efficient but would be easier to read) to do the whole thing, but I'm too busy to re-code it :P

Comment: Shame, this won't work for 2D geometries.... it seems only adapted for 1D lines and actually only generates 1D lines for the result. Could this possibly be extended to 2D lines with multiple segments? Please take a look at the edit to original question above

Comment: Sorry, I hate to take this answer back but this code is super complicated, and can only handle 1D geometries... There has got to be an easier way than this that is easily generalizable to cases where the line layers are not necessarily collinear

Comment: @user32882 You are free to do what you want, but this is called "moving the goalposts." I answered the question you asked exactly. I even checked beforehand if all your points were 1-D. You said yes. If you wanted something different, you should've asked for something different. I suggest submitting a new question asking whatever you're really trying to accomplish.

Comment: I did say I wanted to extend it to 2D... quote: "Yees I am working with actual 1D lines for this test. In reality however I wish to implement this for a 2D road network ". You did answer the question, but the code fails to extend to 2D. If it can, then I would please ask you to explain how so that I can at least try to implement it myself

Comment: My bad for missing that. I would do the same thing but you'll have to parameterize your roads using their along-road lengths and the process would be the same.