# shapely within and contain methods don't work the way I think they should

Tags: python, shapely

I am using Python 3.6 with the latest version of shapely from Anaconda.

```
from shapely.geometry import Point,LineString
g = LineString(coordinates=[(0, 0), (6.656423206909781, 4.437570291332059)])
p  =wkt.loads('POINT (4.160264504318614 2.773481432082537)')
g.contains(p)
>>> False
```

The point `p` is *clearly* within geometry `g`, Since:

```
g.interpolate(5).xy
>>> (array('d', [4.160264504318614]), array('d', [2.773481432082537]))
```

Why is the above statement evaluating to false when I think it should be true?

Comment: @BERA `g` contains its half-way point: `g.contains(g.interpolate(0.5, True))` - is True, so lines can contain points. Note it doesn't contain its 0.25-way point.

Comment: Why doesn't it contain its 0.25 way point?

Comment: *shapely* thinks it doesn't contain its 0.25-way point.

Comment: is this documented? Where can I find this? Seems a bit arbitrary and irrational that only the half way point is contained....

Comment: I can only think this is a numeric precision issue, much like R's FAQ 7.31 https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f but the distance of the point is identically zero so the "contains" algorithm must be doing something else...

Comment: Basically the question boils down to: `g.contains(g.interpolate(0.25,True))` is `False` and `g.contains(g.interpolate(0.5,True))` is `True` and surely all points interpolated on a line are contained in the line.

Comment: Its not *only* the halfway point. I suspect there are other points but I've not found any yet. Floating point math is hard.

Comment: I'm sure the shapely developers will be happy to refund your purchase price if it doesn't meet your needs and you can then go off a write your own library. :-)

Comment: shapely developers can do what they want. I'm just a user on stackexchange trying to find a solution to my limited problem.

Comment: This is more rant than question. Please tone down the stridency in your question to make it more appropriate for professional settings.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291725/determine-if-shapely-point-is-within-a-linestring-multilinestring/21295192#21295192

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply look at the answer of Mike T in [Determine if shapely point is within a linestring/multilinestring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21295192)

> There are floating point precision errors when finding a point on a line. Use the distance with an appropriate threshold instead.

```
 g.distance(p) < 1e-8  # True
 True
```

Comment: I would retort by the same argument as @ds_user... namely how can we automate the selection of a suitable threshhold? This is part of a generic program for which the input data will be varied, and inevitably require different threshholds. For some data a threshhold may be too large and for other data it may be too small. Please also see this question which is why I need to be able to do this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297406/overlay-two-linestring-objects-in-geopandas-accounting-for-the-attributes

Comment: see [Shapely intersections vs shapely relationships - inexact?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33900068/835653)

Comment: how to determine the machine epsilon? Is it consistent throughout (independent of geometry type, machine)? in that case it might make sense to use a threshhold....

Comment: The  [JTS Topology Suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JTS_Topology_Suite) give me the same result (false)  so it's not just a shapely problem.

Comment: In this example can I simply replace `1e-8` as you have in your boolean statement by something like `print(numpy.finfo(float).eps)`? How can I figure out the exact precision used by shapely, which should work for all line/point data regardless of its projection (CRS), extent or size

Comment: If  you want to determine the epsilon value, you can also use the Approximation algorithm in [Machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon). In my case, it is 2.220446049250313e-16 (same as numpy)

Comment: Something is still unclear. If the distance calculation will always evaluate to true as long as the threshold is inferior to machine epsilon, and the `distance` method uses seemingly the same "precision mode" as the `within` method (since they are both part of the same library `shapely`) then why is the `within` method not machine epsilon aware? i.e why does it not do this check on its own without involving the user? It almost feels like I have to make my own `within` method which checks for machine epsilon and throw away the `shapely` method. Doesn't seem right...

Comment: It is a [GEOS](https://trac.osgeo.org/geos) problem (shapely is based on the GEOS  library). (if you want more details,post a message on  [shapely issues](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues))

Answer (score 2):

Taking your original example:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point,LineString
g = LineString(coordinates=[(0, 0), (6.656423206909781, 4.437570291332059)])
p  =wkt.loads('POINT (4.160264504318614 2.773481432082537)')
g.contains(p)
```

my first thought was that the *string* representation of a floating point number can be something that can not be represented exactly by a computer as a floating-point number in 8 bytes. For a trivial example, if I type 1.2222 and keep typing 2s, eventually python can't keep that precision and shows the last digit as a 3:

```
>>> 1.22222222222222222
1.2222222222222223
```

[ There's a nice intro to floating point here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html ]

So a better test is to take the number *from Python's calculation itself* rather than typing them into a text string in a WKT. So I tried:

```
>>> g.interpolate(0.5, True).xy
(array('d', [3.3282116034548905]), array('d', [2.2187851456660295]))
```

Now that return value is stored in Python in whatever precision it is using. That point looks reasonably as half-way along the line, so lets try it:

```
>>> g.contains(g.interpolate(0.5, True))
True
```

Okay, that seems fine. But maybe halfway is somehow special because computers work with binary numbers and division by two is easy in binary? Anyway, always a good idea to try some more tests. Lets' try another point, this time a little bit past halfway:

```
>>> g.contains(g.interpolate(0.50001, True))
False
```

Now *that* perhaps is a little surprising. This shows directly that a point interpolated on a line is no longer thought to be contained by that line.

I wondered if numeric precision was having this effect. So I tried computing the distance from these interpolated points to the line:

```
>>> g.distance(g.interpolate(0.5, True))
0.0
>>> g.distance(g.interpolate(0.50001, True))
0.0
```

And these zeroes are identical zeroes.

I suspect floating point arithmetic rounding errors in the `contains` method are occurring here. If you want to detect if a point is on a line then you should perhaps use the `distance` method and then test the result is less than some small threshold to account for any precision problems.

Comment: II prefer not to go for the distance method, this is to be part of a generic program which should be able to take large vector files of any shape and size and for which a threshhold is not applicable. These points are known to be within the lines from the get-go. The distance method is more for points which are slightly or drastically offset from a line, not for points which we know are on the line...Here's another question I wrote which is somewhat related to the above https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297406/overlay-two-linestring-objects-in-geopandas-accounting-for-the-attributes